# get $_POST Data of a multiple select feeded by jQuery does not work

Tags: php, jquery

I have to multiple `<select>` fields. The first is containing all datasets of list of articles in a table. The second select will be another list of selected articles.

I am using jQuery to pass articles from one select to the other. That works as expected.

The problem is, that if I submit the form, no values are shown in the $_POST. I cannot figure it out. I tried in on a small scale with phpFiddle and the HTML works. So I don't know, it seems that passing the `<option>` via jQuery is the problem.

It works if I put `<option>` fields in the `#target` without jQuery.

Interestingly even the first select, which `<options>` are created via PHP on base of a query, does not show up in the `$_POST` either. So I read about this term on different sites. But the suggested method using an array as a name (as I do) does not work.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<select name="src[]" id="src" multiple>
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
</select>

INSERTED VALUES VIA JQUERY
<select name="target[]" id="target" multiple>
<option value="1">a</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
print_r($_POST);
}
?>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#src').on('click', function() {
        var options = $('select#src option:selected').clone();
        $('select#target').append(options);
        $('select#src option:selected').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values where not shown in the $_POST because I have to select the new fields in the 2nd multiple . Of course, if I do not select an option, it does not show up.